# Como armazenar de forma segura em um app mobile, coleções de dados sensíveis?

Tags: node.js

De modo a ilustrar minha dúvida de forma mais clara, pense que estou querendo produzir um app baseada no objetivo primaria atingido pelo [KeyPass](https://keepass.info/) ou [1Password](https://1password.com/), ou seja, guardar dados sensíveis de forma segura.

Meu objetivo é criar um app (mobile, totalmente independente de recursos externos, ex: até mesmo a base de dados deve ser local) minimalista para persistência segura de dados. Em teoria, as tecnologias base para suportar este App seriam NodeJS + React Native. O usuário irá imputar uma coleção de dados, que podem ir desde usuário, senha, email, notas até o infinito e além. O arquivo de dados (cofre) - pensei em sqlite, precisa ser seguro de modo que, se alguém tiver acesso a este, não consiga acessar os dados sensíveis do usuário. pois seria necessário conhecer a chave de acesso.

Os dados serão mantidos no dispositivo do usuário, podendo ser sincronizado via serviços como icloud, google drive e assim por diante.

Principais dúvidas:

1) sqlite realmente seria o mais adequado para este caso? Se sim, qual seria a proposta mais viável para proteção, criptografar o arquivo de dados inteiro?

2) Cheguei a ler alguns artigos que falavam de criptografia com nodejs, porém, nestes o arquivo de dados era descriptografado e criptografado sempre que uma nova alteração ou leitura dos dados precisava ser feita. É assim mesmo que um cofre de dados para a finalidade citada acima funciona?

Comment: Fora a isso a pergunta é genérica demais e não tem muito o que inventar. Qiando falamos em segurança uma coisa sempre é certa, a experiência da pessoa com o assunto é o que conta. O fato da pessoa achar que magicamente obterá segurança seguindo alguma receita de bolo já é uma luz vermelha que provavelmente não terá segurança ali.

Comment: A forma convencional de segurança é enviando isso para o banco de dados ou para back-end. Mas nem tudo é 100% seguro... ainda não existiu algo tão seguro que não possa ser hackeado. Por isso segurança deve vir também com constantes atualizações...

Comment: sim este ponto eu compreendo perfeitamente. Mas minha dúvida está em como poderia ser trilhado um caminho para prover um cofre de dados seguro que coexista localmente com a aplicação? Resumindo esse seria o alvo da pergunta.